# is there a way to view ALB access logs on S3 in real-time?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-alb

I'm a newb; here's how I'm currently attempting to view the latest activity in my ALB access logs on S3:

1. aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/super/long/path/that/seems/to/never/end/
2. visually identify the latest log file
3. aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/super/long/path/that/seems/to/never/end/latest_file.gz .
4. gunzip latest_file.gz
5. view latest_file

Do you have a better way to view the latest file for activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Athena service for achieving this. Athena is a querying service for S3 and can be used like any other sql on a DB(like TSQL on MSSQL).
https://aws.amazon.com/athena/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc